# Can anyone protect my question (What does “TTY” stand for?)

Tags: support

Can anyone protect my [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for)?  Because there are samlier question to it like this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472175/why-it-is-sudo) that is protected! That has less upvotes!

Answer (score -2):

I have protected that question but you must have to read why a question should get protected

https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/protect-questions

Its doesnt matter its having low/high votes. If that have some significance to wide area of Ask Ubuntu users, then to protect it we used to protect the Question.

So the others(new users) who are intended to do some mess cant even touch them unless they do some contribution and earn a minimum reputation.